# The type cannot be used as type parameter TRole in the generic type or method UserStore

Tags: c#, identity

I am trying to build an Identity Server using [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/index.html) and ASP.NET Core MVC 1.0.1 in Visual Studio 2015. I already successfully setup the `ConfigurationStore` and `OperationalStore` using EntityFramework Core 1.0.1 ([section 8](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html)).

This is what my `project.json` file looks like (partial):

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App" {
            "version": "1.0.1",
            "type": "platform"
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
        /////// Entity Framework /////////
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1", 
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
        /////// ASP.NET Identity /////////
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity": "1.0.0",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
        /////// Identity Server //////////
        "IdentityServer4": "1.0.0-rc1-update2",
        "IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity": "1.0.0-rc1-update2",
        "IdentityServer4.EntityFramework": "1.0.0-rc1-update2",
        ......
    }
}
```

I am trying to use ASP.NET Identity as my user store in the Identity Server described in [section 6](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html). By default the ASP.NET Identity uses `string` as the key for all the tables but I want to use `int` so I changed them like this:

```
public class AppUserToken : IdentityUserToken<int> { }
public class AppUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }
public class AppUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class AppRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<int> { }
public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int, AppUserRole, AppRoleClaim> { }
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin>
```

And then I need to create custom user and role store like this:

```
public class AppRoleStore : RoleStore<AppRole, AppIdentityDbContext, int, AppUserRole, AppRoleClaim>
{
    public AppRoleStore(AppIdentityDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null)
        : base(context, describer)
    {}

    .......
}

public class AppUserStore : UserStore<AppUser, AppRole, AppIdentityDbContext, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppUserToken>
{
    public AppUserStore(AppIdentityDbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) 
        : base(context, describer)
    { }

    ............
}
```

Last but not least, my `AppIdentityDbContext`:

```
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int, AppUserClaim, AppUserRole, AppUserLogin, AppRoleClaim, AppUserToken>
{
    public AppIdentityDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppIdentityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    public override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<AppUser>().ToTable("Users");
        builder.Entity<AppUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        builder.Entity<AppUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        builder.Entity<AppUserToken>().ToTable("UserTokens");

        builder.Entity<AppRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        builder.Entity<AppRoleClaim>().ToTable("RoleClaims");

        builder.Entity<AppUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
    }
}
```

But I am getting a build error on `AppUserStore`:
*The type AppRole cannot be used as type parameter 'TRole' in the generic type or method 'UserStore'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'AppRole' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityRole>'.*

wtf?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing the `IdentityUserRole` twice: for the `Role` and for the `UserRole`.

```
public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
public class AppRole :     IdentityUserRole<int, AppUserRole, AppRoleClaim> { }
```

Your AppRole should inherit from `IdentityRole`, not `IdentityUserRole`:

```
public class AppRole : IdentityRole...
```

Comment: that was a typo. I made sure in my code that AppRole inherits from IdentityRole not IdentityUserRole. It would have given me other errors otherwise. I have updated my post. Sorry about that!